# Sql join back to self by many to many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, self-join

In need some sql help (pgsql, prefer general sql join or subselect syntax):

```
entity (id, name)

tag (id, name)

entity_tag (entity_id, tag_id)
```

I need to be able to feed a query with a set of tag ids (like 1, 2, 3). I want it to return a list of all tags that are connected (by the entity_tag table) to entities having one or more of the given tags. Like "what else is similar entities tagged with" in common terms.

What would be the simplest and best performing sql for that purpose?

Comment: What sql? What database server do you use?

Comment: Postgres, looking for a working select query.

Comment: It's really helpful in questions like this if you provide *sample data*. Ideally `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. Plus an explanation of the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct t.id, t.name
from
    (
        select distinct entity_id
        from entity_tag
        where tag_id in (1, 2, 3)
    ) e
    inner join
    entity_tag et using (entity_id)
    inner join
    tag t on t.id = et.tag_id
```

The subselect gets all entities that have at least one of the supplied tags. Then it is joined to entity_tag to get all tags of the previously subselected entities. The final join gets the names of those tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM tag 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT id from entity_tag)
```

Comment: I think some additional text here to explain the solution would be helpful

Comment: Please see the explanation in my question. I need other tags that is connected to entities that have one or more of a given set of tags. So if entity 1 have tags 1, 2, 3 then if I give the query (that I am looking for) tag id 1, i get tag 2 and 3 because of that entity, since it had tag 1 (that was among the ids fed to the query).